# How to automatically regenerate DB partial project files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-dbpro

I am using advanced version of Visual Studio 2010 and using database projects. There's a feature of exporting database schema as partial project (which creates `*.files` output file), but it is triggered manually by the developer (you need to right-click on the project and select *Export as partial project*). I would like to automatize this process, meaning that the output file is created each time I modify the database, I build it OR I close the solution.

I tried creating a macro, which executes a [DTE command Project.VSDBExportAsPartialProject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470565.aspx#PartialProjects), but sometimes it fails with an exception AND it shows a *Save as* dialog box, which I would like to avoid. Maybe the idea is to add it to the post-build event, but I don't know how to execute DTE commands from there.

To sum up, all I need is to automatically refresh the `*.files` output file located in fixed path without any user interactions.

Is it possible?